# Extending Web Application for BI

Tags: business-intelligence, bi

My web application has 3 site collections. The 3 site collections are based on the Business Intelligence template. Everything is working fine using windows auth. The solution requires me to extend (create a new IIS site) the web application facing the internet and using fba.

My question is, will any corrections made on the old application and it's corresponding site collections be reflected in the extended app?

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2010 we are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

All content modifications made inside the site collections in your web application will be visible across all websites, no matter where users are coming from and how they authenticate.

However, if you configure the zone using Windows Authentication for Kerberos in order to have identity delegation - this functionality will not be available for your forms based users in the other zone. SharePoint has no way to transform the forms based identity to a Windows identity or to delegate these credentials to a backend datasource.